# request.POST.getlist returning None list in Django?

Tags: django

I have a html template like this:

```
<table border="1" align="center">

{% for result in result %}
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice }}" /></td>
<td><label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice }}</label><br /></td>
<td>{{ result.file_name }}</td>
<td>{{ result.type }}</td>
<td>{{ result.size }}</td>
<td>{{ result.end_date }}</td>
<td>{{ result.source }}</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
</table>
{{ c }}
<h4><a href="/delete_files/">Delete File</a></h4>
```

`result variable` is generated from:

```
def uploaded_files(request):
    log_id = request.user.id
    b = File.objects.filter(users_id=log_id, flag='F') #Get the user id from session .delete() to use delete
    return render_to_response('upload.html',  {'result': b}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This is where I try to get the value from choice from template:

```
def delete_files(request):
    log_id = request.user.id
    choices = request.POST.getlist('choice') #Get the file name from the as a list
    for i in choices:
        File.objects.filter(users_id=log_id, file_name=i).update(flag='D')
    return render_to_response('upload.html', {'c': choices}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: There is no `form` tag in your template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Rohan mentioned in the comment, you have no `<form>` tag in the template, and appear to be simply assuming that clicking on a normal `<a>` link will submit some data. That's not at all how it works: if you want to submit data from input elements, they need to be inside a `<form>`, you need to set the `action` of that form appropriately, and you need to submit it using a `<input type="submit">` (or `button`) rather than a link.

This is basic HTML, by the way, not Django.

Comment: But Daniel what if I want seperate buttons like Delete, Share! For delete I want to process delete_files but for share I want to process share_files. How can I do that? I can only specify 1 view action in form.

Comment: You can have multiple submit buttons, and the values of the relevant one will be included in the POST data. You can use that value within your view to dispatch to the correct function.

Comment: You mean if I put: <form action="/delete_files/" method="post">, can I access the POST value in shared_files views too?

Comment: No. I mean your action should point to a combined dispatch function, but you have two submit buttons, one with `name='delete'` and one with `name='share'`, then in the view you check to see which of those elements is in request.POST and call the relevant function.

Comment: Hi Danial. It is always recommended that first check field name in request dict. as [`if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:`](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07.html) But if I uses [`QueryDict.getlist()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) as doc says *`"It’s guaranteed to return a list of some sort unless the default value was no list."`* So for select-multiple I don't checks field name I just do `L = request.POST.getlist('fieldname')` then use list `L`.  Is there any harm in doing so? Am I correct?

Answer (score 5):

Include [] after choice because you are getting array form request

`choices = request.POST.getlist('choice[]')`

this will solve your prob

Comment: No it doesn't. I am still getting empty list.

Comment: where you passing the post data

Comment: for that view you need to pass the data form template. use query string  to pass data

Comment: Please read my question carefully. I have passed the data from uploaded_files and I am accessing the data from delete_files.

Comment: Now you under stand what am saying and for delete, share you can use Ajax, jQuery i preferred this. its easy to use :)